# Function in select statement doesn't return value when using max and query has a null field

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I execute the following query, it brings me return:

```
select  max(get_description(sequence)) description
from    table
where   sequence = :existent_sequence;
```

```
"DESCRIPTION"   
"Solu-Medrol 500 mg  FA"
```

Obs.: get_description is a function.

But, when I add one more field, both fields return null:

```
select  max(get_description(sequence)) description,
        max(due_date) due_date
from    table
where   sequence = :existent_sequence;
```

```
"DESCRIPTION"             "DUE_DATE"
null                       null
```

I realized that when I add a field that can not be null, the query works:

```
select  max(get_description(sequence)) description,
        max(due_date) due_date,
        max(sequence) sequence
from    table
where   sequence = :existent_sequence;
```

```
"DESCRIPTION"             "DUE_DATE"    "SEQUENCE"
"Solu-Medrol 500 mg  FA"   null          12542
```

...but due_date is a field that can be null.

I don't understand why it's happening, could anyone help me?

I'm using Oracle 19c (19.7)

Comment: And what does get_description() function do?  You need to post a [mcve] - all relevant code, table DDL, sample data,

Comment: Is this SQL standalone or are you taking it from a larger SQL? We'd need to see the whole thing. And ditto for seeing the function code. Also check that there aren't any materialized views causing a query rewrite - generate an explain plan for each and ensure the same table object is used in each.

Comment: Also, run these without the MAX's and compare the output.

Comment: Please post a complete reproducible example. This behavior is very strange and such obvious bug is unlikely to be released

Comment: Hi guys, I found the problem. The database has a row level security for the table and a "filter predicate" for the field due_date. I realized this when I generate an explain plan for the query. I can't understand explain plans so I research a little bit about it. Thank you for the tips and for the help!